# open a csv file for testing but myfile.is_open() return false

Tags: c++, csv, c++11, c++14

I'm trying to open a csv file for testing but it always comes back to me "" Unable to open file "" and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. can anyone help me?

```
void testBSTWithInteger() {
    string line;
    ifstream myfile ("C:\\Users\\danie\\Desktop\\DatastructuresV2\\tests\\bstint.csv");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while ( getline (myfile,line) )
        {
            char c[line.length()];
            strcpy(c, line.c_str());
            auto bst = new BST<int>();

            for (int i= 0; i<line.length(); i++) {
                if (c[i] == 2) {
                    bst->insert(c[i]-48);
                    assert(bst->root->data == 2);
                    assert(bst->root->left == nullptr);
                }
                if (c[i] == 1) {
                    bst->insert(c[i]-48);
                    assert(bst->root->left->data == 1);
                }
                if (c[i] == 3) {
                    bst->insert(c[i]-48);
                    assert(bst->root->right->data == 3);
                    bst->deleteNode(2);
                    assert(bst->root->data == 3);
                    bst->deleteNode(3);
                    assert(bst->root->data == 1);
                    bst->deleteNode(1);
                    assert(bst->root == NULL);
                }
            }
        }
        myfile.close();
    }
    else cout << "Unable to open file";
}
```

Comment: Note that `char c[line.length()]; strcpy(c, line.c_str());` is dangerous. You have to allocate one more element for terminating null-character. Also note that variable-length array is non-standard in C++. Why not use elements of `line` directly?

Comment: There can only be one possible explanation: no file with such a name exists. What is the evidence you can show, in your question, that the input file actually exists, and is readable?

Comment: Could be the user is not permissioned for the file?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik the file is present in the same folder where the test.cpp file is located

Comment: My guess is your name is Daniel, not "danie"

Comment: The question is not whether "the file is present in the same folder where the test.cpp is located", but whether the file with the specified filename exists.

Comment: lol, @Carlos i know but my pc user is "danie" :P

Comment: Ok, seemed a reasonable guess. Make sure you can cd all the way to the file, and that you can read it from the command line. Then it's present and permissioned, and the error won't be something trivial.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik the names are correct, I just checked

Comment: @Carlos from the command line I can cd to the folder and then open the file

Comment: I didn't ask you to check anything, but to show some kind of proof that a flie of that name exists.

Comment: Is there some other program you can use where you can paste in the exact same string, and the file opens?

Comment: Are you sure the file name is `bstint.csv` instead of `bstint.csv.csv`?